# Why is my git icon not working in Juypter Notebook?

Tags: r, github, jupyter-notebook

My git icon turns dark and it doesn't work at all. And my TA has no idea of how to get it done too.
[git icon1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3QoIX.png)

[git icon2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1QVuw.png)

[git icon3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AqAx.png)

I have no idea of what to do and I can't remember what I did in the past cuz it can work in the past.
How do you think I could make it work again?